# Any way to change the color of drawing pen in OneNote?

Tags: onenote, onenote-api

[image: Brush Color in OneNote]

Greeting All,

I am trying to find a way or any API which can change the color of the pen brush in OneNote. 
The purpose is to let users can use custom colors to draw or to text.

The existing official doc seems cannot provide the answer. Please suggest if any.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Onenote is really abysmal, as far as I'm aware, there is no API supported to do anything like setting pen colour and thickness.
Though it has been asked for many times.
I just want the Radial Menu back!
In the desktop Onenote you can't even change a favourite pen colour or thickness without deleting and readding it.

The best you can do is create a keyboard script to go through the menus from 'Alt'.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a very old topic but I though I could help people who are still looking to have more colours.

Sorry for my bad english, it is not my mother tongue.

I found a way to have any colours in "onenote windows 10".

You need to have an older version of word (version 1901 works fine). If you have a newer version you will need to downgrade. It is easy to to. I detailed how at the end.

Then, in word all the pen will be sync from onenote. From Word you will be able to add pen and customize the colours settings, with hex value or others.

Then you need to close word and after a while (2 or 3 min) open back onenote. There you should see your newly created pen with custom colours that you are not able to create from onenote only.

To downgrade Office (and so word too). You will need to open a command prompt as administrator and type this command : "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\ClickToRun\officec2rclient.exe" /update user updatetoversion=16.0.11231.20174

This will install the 1901 update that works for me.

Hope it will help some people.